# can't put content from restsharp to db

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am working with some API in C# Winforms. Getting response successfully as a json. The problem is that when I deserialize it the output is just a big string like this:

```
{"orders": [
  {
    "id": 155971090,
    "date_created": "2021-06-18T06:16:31.36202+03:00",
    "date_modified": "2021-06-19T15:10:45.567327+03:00",
    "client_first_name": "Олександр",
    "client_second_name": "",
    "client_last_name": "Бандура",
    "client_id": 133374423,
    "client_avg_rating": 5.0,
    "email": "bandurao@ukr.net",
    "phone": "+380996461421",
    "delivery_option": {
      "id": 13662439,
      "name": "Доставка \"Нова Пошта\""
    },
    "delivery_address": "Ананьїв, №1: вул. Незалежності, 19",
    "delivery_provider_data": {
      "provider": "nova_poshta",
      "type": "W2W",
      "sender_warehouse_id": null,
      "recipient_warehouse_id": "4049834c-e1c2-11e3-8c4a-0050568002cf",
      "declaration_number": null
    },
    "delivery_cost": 0,
    "payment_option": {
      "id": 7451891,
      "name": "Передоплата"
    },
    "payment_data": null,
    "price": "169,72 грн.",
    "full_price": "169,72 грн.",
    "client_notes": "",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 1430223923,
        "external_id": "513.4769",
        "name": "Ремень 4L-240",
        "name_multilang": {
          "ru": "Ремень 4L-240",
          "uk": "Ремінь 4L-240"
        },
        "sku": "4769",
        "price": "21,76 грн.",
        "quantity": 1.0,
        "measure_unit": "шт.",
        "image": "https://images.ua.prom.st/3169964688_w100_h100_remen-4l-240.jpg",
        "url": "https://teomax.com.ua/p1430223923-remen-240.html",
        "total_price": "21,76 грн.",
        "cpa_commission": {
          "amount": "1.00"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 1430222732,
        "external_id": "512.4825",
        "name": "Ремень 240 PJ3",
        "name_multilang": {
          "ru": "Ремень 240 PJ3",
          "uk": "Ремінь 240 PJ3"
        },
        "sku": "4825",
        "price": "48,96 грн.",
        "quantity": 1.0,
        "measure_unit": "шт.",
        "image": "https://images.ua.prom.st/3170015051_w100_h100_remen-240-pj3.jpg",
        "url": "https://teomax.com.ua/p1430222732-remen-240-pj3.html",
        "total_price": "48,96 грн.",
        "cpa_commission": {
          "amount": "2.25"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 1430230819,
        "external_id": "297.2885",
        "name": "Масло \"двухтактное\" (2Т), 1л",
        "name_multilang": {
          "ru": "Масло \"двухтактное\" (2Т), 1л",
          "uk": "Масло \"двотактне\" (2Т), 1л"
        },
        "sku": "2885",
        "price": "99 грн.",
        "quantity": 1.0,
        "measure_unit": "шт.",
        "image": "https://images.ua.prom.st/3169999571_w100_h100_maslo-dvuhtaktnoe-2t.jpg",
        "url": "https://teomax.com.ua/p1430230819-maslo-dvuhtaktnoe.html",
        "total_price": "99 грн.",
        "cpa_commission": {
          "amount": "4.55"
        }
      }
    ],
    "status": "delivered",
    "status_name": "Выполнен",
    "source": "portal",
    "price_with_special_offer": null,
    "special_offer_discount": null,
    "special_offer_promocode": null,
    "has_order_promo_free_delivery": false,
    "cpa_commission": {
      "amount": "7.80",
      "is_refunded": false
    },
    "utm": null
  },
  {
    "id": 155896081,
    "date_created": "2021-06-17T13:11:40.241146+03:00",
    "date_modified": "2021-06-17T13:42:55.021203+03:00",
    "client_first_name": "Антон",
    "client_second_name": "",
    "client_last_name": "Подосельник",
    "client_id": 133299120,
    "client_avg_rating": 5.0,
    "email": "a.n.podoselnik@gmail.com",
    "phone": "+380992764450",
    "delivery_option": {
      "id": 13662439,
      "name": "Доставка \"Нова Пошта\""
    },
    "delivery_address": "Киев, №132 (до 30 кг): просп. Леся Курбаса, 16-А",
    "delivery_provider_data": {
      "provider": "nova_poshta",
      "type": "W2W",
      "sender_warehouse_id": null,
      "recipient_warehouse_id": "51b6c251-7a06-11e4-acce-0050568002cf",
      "declaration_number": null
    },
    "delivery_cost": 0,
    "payment_option": {
      "id": 7451890,
      "name": "Готівкою"
    },
    "payment_data": null,
    "price": "254,30 грн.",
    "full_price": "254,30 грн.",
    "client_notes": "",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 1430208419,
        "external_id": "250.4391",
        "name": "Подшипник шариковый 12*30*8",
        "name_multilang": {
          "ru": "Подшипник шариковый 12*30*8",
          "uk": "Підшипник кульковий 12*30*8"
        },
        "sku": "4391",
        "price": "50,86 грн.",
        "quantity": 5.0,
        "measure_unit": "шт.",
        "image": "https://images.ua.prom.st/3169911780_w100_h100_podshipnik-sharikovyj-12308.jpg",
        "url": "https://teomax.com.ua/p1430208419-podshipnik-sharikovyj-12308.html",
        "total_price": "254,30 грн.",
        "cpa_commission": {
          "amount": "5.08"
        }
      }
    ],
    "status": "canceled",
    "status_name": "Отменен",
    "source": "portal",
    "price_with_special_offer": null,
    "special_offer_discount": null,
    "special_offer_promocode": null,
    "has_order_promo_free_delivery": false,
    "cpa_commission": {
      "amount": "5.08",
      "is_refunded": true
    },
    "utm": null
  },
  {
    "id": 155881650,
    "date_created": "2021-06-17T11:36:11.87828+03:00",
    "date_modified": "2021-06-17T13:10:11.527256+03:00",
    "client_first_name": "Антон",
    "client_second_name": "",
    "client_last_name": "Подосельник",
    "client_id": 133299120,
    "client_avg_rating": 5.0,
    "email": "a.n.podoselnik@gmail.com",
    "phone": "+380992764450",
    "delivery_option": {
      "id": 13662439,
      "name": "Доставка \"Нова Пошта\""
    },
    "delivery_address": "Киев, №132 (до 30 кг): просп. Леся Курбаса, 16-А",
    "delivery_provider_data": {
      "provider": "nova_poshta",
      "type": "W2W",
      "sender_warehouse_id": null,
      "recipient_warehouse_id": "51b6c251-7a06-11e4-acce-0050568002cf",
      "declaration_number": null
    },
    "delivery_cost": 0,
    "payment_option": {
      "id": 7451890,
      "name": "Готівкою"
    },
    "payment_data": null,
    "price": "305,16 грн.",
    "full_price": "305,16 грн.",
    "client_notes": "",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 1430208419,
        "external_id": "250.4391",
        "name": "Подшипник шариковый 12*30*8",
        "name_multilang": {
          "ru": "Подшипник шариковый 12*30*8",
          "uk": "Підшипник кульковий 12*30*8"
        },
        "sku": "4391",
        "price": "50,86 грн.",
        "quantity": 6.0,
        "measure_unit": "шт.",
        "image": "https://images.ua.prom.st/3169911780_w100_h100_podshipnik-sharikovyj-12308.jpg",
        "url": "https://teomax.com.ua/p1430208419-podshipnik-sharikovyj-12308.html",
        "total_price": "305,16 грн.",
        "cpa_commission": {
          "amount": "6.10"
        }
      }
    ],
    "status": "canceled",
    "status_name": "Отменен",
    "source": "portal",
    "price_with_special_offer": null,
    "special_offer_discount": null,
    "special_offer_promocode": null,
    "has_order_promo_free_delivery": false,
    "cpa_commission": {
      "amount": "6.10",
      "is_refunded": true
    },
    "utm": null
  }
]}
```

My function to get this is like this:

```
public IRestResponse GetOrders()
{
    var connection = new RestClient("https://my.prom.ua/api/v1/");
    connection.UseNewtonsoftJson();

    var request = new RestRequest("orders/list", Method.GET, DataFormat.None);
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer token");
            
    var response = connection.Get(request);
    //var things = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response.Content);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    return response;
}
```

Then I tried to make json object out of it and deserialize:

```
var jsonString = JToken.Parse(data.Content);
            
var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString.ToString());
```

How can I make key value pair out of this and be able to put data into a db table?

Comment: How exactly do you want to make it into key/value pairs? There's several objects with child objects, how does that work as key/value? Pleaase provide more information, for example the end result you're after.

Comment: Somethin like     'orders' ("id"=> 155971090, 'client_firstname'=>'somevalue' product ())

Comment: The bigest problem for me that that object order is only one object. So it doesn't basicly considering child objects as objects. To me it sims like a one big string

Comment: Though SQL server has [built in support for unstructured data like XML & JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) the bigger question is _why you want to do so in the first place?_ Are you storing the data temporarily for some sort of EAI/ETL solution?  Storing JSON in a non-SQL database might not be terribly efficient otherwise

Comment: That will be greate. But I have an other restriction I have to use Access and an other proble that column names of a client's table aren't really similar to the object names. So I am trying to make somethin like 'name'=myobject['client_first_name']

Comment: Ok. in wich direction Should I move with this?